# static_cast<unsigned> vs static_cast<unsigned int>

Tags: c++, casting, resharper

I'm new to C++, so please take this lightly.
I was using resharper to convert some code from c-style casts to c++ style casts.

This code here:

```
(unsigned int)(ch - start) <= (unsigned int)(end - start);
```

Was changed to

```
static_cast<unsigned>(ch - start) <= static_cast<unsigned>(end - start);
```

instead of:

```
static_cast<unsigned int>(ch - start) <= static_cast<unsigned int>(end - start);
```

Is there ANY difference? And also, is there any peformance differences? This is called **billions** of times.

Comment: There isn't any difference. The two mean the same thing. By convention, the `int` part is often omitted.

Comment: @Ron What about performance?

Comment: `unsigned int` and `unsigned` by itself mean the same thing.  In the `unsigned` by itself case, the `int` is implied.  There is no performance difference.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Got it Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there ANY difference?

`unsigned int` has 4 more characters than `unsigned`. There are no other differences.

> And also, is there any peformance differences?

No.